# Regex : findall with a repeated capture group

Tags: regex-group

I would like to understand why :

```
re.findall(r"(\d[A-Za-z]+)", "My user name is 3e4r 5fg")
```

returns

```
['3e', '4r', '5fg']
```

while :

```
re.findall(r"(\d[A-Za-z]+)+", "My user name is 3e4r 5fg")
```

returns

```
['4r', '5fg']
```

I tested some combinations with spaces between groups of "digit-letter" and 2 points clearly are involved in :

1. spaces between those groups
2. last "+".

I don't really understand why adding "+" after the group changes the result. Can someone explain me the steps of the process which leads to those different answers? Thank you very much.

Comment: because + makes to match the whole group minimum ones

Comment: You are using a repeated capturing group `(...)+`, so it will try and match **consecutive** occurrences of the pattern in the capture group greedily. This causes one instance of the pattern `(\d[A-Za-z]+)+` to consume both adjacent occurrences in "3e4r". Repeated capture groups in RegEx only return the last matched occurence, so you end up with the result of "4r" for the first match of the pattern found by `re.findall()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 
@zr0gravity7, if i well understood what you said, the second regex found the first instance "3e4r", which is the double time pattern, then the second "5fg". I would like to understand why it returns "4r" and not the "group" "3e4r", since it's the first instance. Why return the last matched occurence and not just the whole group ?

Comment: "the second regex" there is only one regex, `re`'s `findall()` simplies performs a single match operation multiple times, picking up where it left off. `findall`'s first matching of the pattern against the string consumes "3e" then consumes "4r" (due to the repetition) **in a single match**. The second matching picks up after that, and consumes (without repetition) "5fg". To understand why repeated capture groups capture only the last matched occurrence, here is a good link: https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Answer (score 0):

When you put + after parenthesis you are searching for a pattern that contains one or more sub pattern with 1 digit and (one or more) letters'
so this phrase: `"(\d[A-Za-z]+)+"` return 2 matches:

1. 3e4r
2. 5fg

When you put a sub-pattern in parenthesis it means that all matches this sub-pattern will enter in a group, the groups is:

1. 3e
2. 5fg

The function `re.findall` returns only the groups (Unless there are no groups then it returns the matches ).